# Reusing an inspiron 11z as "headless"

Tags: boot, laptop, display, bios, dell-inspiron

My old Inspiron 11 got its display broken and I decided it could be used as a desktop simply by removing the display. I stripped everything out and I got only the box with the keyboard and the mousepad but I decided to keep the internal display plugged just to see everything was working and indeed, the BIOS loaded nicely and consistently booted up using an USB with Ubuntu. I then connected it to a monitor from HDMI included in the laptop, unplug the internal display and power the computer again. For my surprise, this time the BIOS didn't finish loading and kinda freeze (it allowed me to press F2 for setup but never reached it). Out of curiosity, I plugged again the internal display and this time the BIOS loaded without any issue.

I'd find strange that the BIOS would be locked by failing to contact the display. Does anyone knows if that's the case? How can I boot the machine without connecting the internal display?

I hope I can find help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly a BIOS issue. There may or may not be graphic adapter settings to change this (to allow booting without the internal display connection).

As a simple recommendation, though, I would leave the internal display connected and simply disable video to that monitor.

Comment: I was afraid of it so I kinda followed your advise. Since I really wanted to get rid of the broken screen, I ended up striping the display off ending just with a small board on the bottom so the BIOS detects the display without been anything truly connected. It feels cheap but it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. For what it's worth, I am glad you got it working even if it's less than ideal. But I feel you... I just hide all my junk in the closet. ;-)